# DBeaver How to Save Export Data Script

Tags: export, dbeaver

DBeaver has excellent Import data/Export data tools, but is it possible to Save the export or import script rather than execute it immediately so that it can be executed at a later time?

I need to migrate a production database so I want to prepare all of the scripts beforehand and then execute them all when it's time to do the switch.

Comment: did you end up solving this? im trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @rannirabadi - I created an open source project instead: https://github.com/isapir/Migrate2Postgres

Answer (score 1):

You can save your scripts from menu [SQL editor]->[Save SQL script].

Then in project panel you can create link on folder that contains your saved scripts or on script itself.

Also there is a [Script Management guide](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Script-Management) on DBreaver Git wiki.

Comment: Know it is not so relevant anymore, but I found this question when trying to solve similar issue.

Comment: This is not the question that I asked. The question is about saving scripts that are auto-generated by DBeaver.  See https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2392

Comment: @isapir sry didn&#39;t get it.
 So, can u post it as answer (no it is couldn&#39;t be executed. With that link). 

Since your question is well indexed in search systems?

Answer (score 0):

The file that contains all dBeaver tasks is a JSON file.

On my computer, it's located in

```
C:\Users\fred\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\.dbeaver\tasks.json
```